# how to read copied file from github from yaml and jq

Tags: azure, github, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am using devops pipeline to read contents of a json file hosted in a private repo in git hub. I can see the file in the pipeline output but jq is not reading the file its giving this error: "jq: error: Could not open file /home/vsts/work/1/s/config.json: No such file or directory"

this is my yaml code:

```
   ---
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: testrepo
    type: github
    endpoint: testendpoint
    name:  test/test01


trigger:
  - none
pool:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604
steps:
  - script: |
      displayName: 'Update the build number in readme.txt' 
      name: JQ
      sudo apt-get install jq
      echo 'installing jq'
  - checkout: testrepo
    path: mytest   # will checkout at $(Pipeline.Workspace)/PutMyCodeHere
  - script: dir ../mytest/

      data=$(jq 'to_entries | map(select(.value.datavalue=="true")) | from_entries' $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/data.json )
      echo "$data"
```

how can i jq to my json file?

Comment: Your testrepo does not seem to have a `data.json` file. What is the output of the checkout step?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi Liu the below answer didn't work unfortunately..

Comment: Hi @rayaurelius, I have edited my answer and add the test code, could you please check it and then share the latest news here, If the issue still occurs, you can kindly share the latest error info here. Thanks

Comment: Hi @rayaurelius, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the same error message and I added task Copy files and Publish build artifacts to check the S folder, then we can see the data.json file.

[image]

It seems that jq issue instead of azure devops pipeline, you can raise the issue to jq support.

As a workaround, we can read the json file via cmd `jq . {file name}.json`

Result:

[image]

**Update1**

My test code:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: vitol
    type: github
    endpoint: GitHubTest
    name:  vitoliutest/vitol

trigger:
  - none
pool:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604
steps:
  - script: |
      displayName: 'Update the build number in readme.txt' 
      name: JQ
      sudo apt-get install jq
      echo 'installing jq'
  - checkout: vitol
    path: mytest   # will checkout at $(Pipeline.Workspace)/PutMyCodeHere

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
      Contents: '**'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'

  - script: dir ../mytest/

      jq . $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/*/data.json
```